# How to I make sprite appear one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

So I'm trying to make it so my sprites appear one by one every time the player clicks one of the wrong buttons and when it gets to the last sprite it prints a text "Lose". I'm not really sure how to do this because I'm new to doing this.

```
wrong buttons are BFHIJPQRSUVXYZ
```

The sprites I want to add

```
D1 = pygame.image.load("D1.png")
D2 = pygame.image.load("D2.png")
D3 = pygame.image.load("D3.png")
D4 = pygame.image.load("D4.png")
D5 = pygame.image.load("D5.png")
D6 = pygame.image.load("D6.png")
D7 = pygame.image.load("D7.png")
D8 = pygame.image.load("D8.png")
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Drawing window screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
# The Name of my window
pygame.display.set_caption("StickMan")
# Drawing the buttons
A = pygame.image.load("A.png")
A1 = pygame.image.load("A1.png")
A2 = pygame.image.load("A2.png")
A3 = pygame.image.load("A3.png")
A4 = pygame.image.load("A4.png")
A5 = pygame.image.load("A5.png")
A6 = pygame.image.load("A6.png")
A7 = pygame.image.load("A7.png")
A8 = pygame.image.load("A8.png")
A9 = pygame.image.load("A9.png")
A10 = pygame.image.load("A10.png")
A11 = pygame.image.load("A11.png")
A12 = pygame.image.load("A12.png")
# stickman sprites
D1 = pygame.image.load("D1.png")
D2 = pygame.image.load("D2.png")
D3 = pygame.image.load("D3.png")
D4 = pygame.image.load("D4.png")
D5 = pygame.image.load("D5.png")
D6 = pygame.image.load("D6.png")
D7 = pygame.image.load("D7.png")
D8 = pygame.image.load("D8.png")

# Button class
class button1():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.clicked = False
    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
 
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
 
    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        return pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width and pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height
 
    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                eat.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False
            

# Color
white = (255,255,255)
Abutton = button1((0,255,0),287,310,55,55, '')       
Bbutton = button1((0,255,0),358,310,55,55, '')
Cbutton = button1((0,255,0),428,310,55,55, '')
Dbutton = button1((0,255,0),504,310,55,55, '')
Ebutton = button1((0,255,0),578,310,55,55, '')
Fbutton = button1((0,255,0),645,310,55,55, '')

Gbutton = button1((0,255,0),0,377,55,55, '')
Hbutton = button1((0,255,0),73,377,55,55, '')
Ibutton = button1((0,255,0),142,377,55,55, '')
Jbutton = button1((0,255,0),212,377,55,55, '')
Kbutton = button1((0,255,0),287,377,55,55, '')
Lbutton = button1((0,255,0),358,377,55,55, '')
Mbutton = button1((0,255,0),428,377,55,55, '')
Nbutton = button1((0,255,0),504,377,55,55, '')
Obutton = button1((0,255,0),578,377,55,55, '')
Pbutton = button1((0,255,0),645,377,55,55, '')

Qbutton = button1((0,255,0),0,445,55,55, '')
Rbutton = button1((0,255,0),73,445,55,55, '')
Sbutton = button1((0,255,0),142,445,55,55, '')
Tbutton = button1((0,255,0),212,445,55,55, '')
Ubutton = button1((0,255,0),287,445,55,55, '')
Vbutton = button1((0,255,0),358,445,55,55, '')
Wbutton = button1((0,255,0),428,445,55,55, '')
Xbutton = button1((0,255,0),504,445,55,55, '')
Ybutton = button1((0,255,0),578,445,55,55, '')
Zbutton = button1((0,255,0),645,445,55,55, '')

def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(A,(0,0))
    if Abutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A1,(0,0))
    if Cbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A2,(0,0))
    if Kbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A3,(0,0))
    if Nbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A4,(0,0))
    if Obutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A5,(0,0))
    if Wbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A6,(0,0))
    if Lbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A7,(0,0))
    if Ebutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A8,(0,0))
    if Dbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A9,(0,0))
    if Gbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A10,(0,0))
    if Mbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A11,(0,0))
    if Tbutton.clicked:
        window.blit(A12,(0,0))


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            #CKNOWLEDGMT
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if Abutton.isOver(pos):
                Abutton.clicked = True
            if Cbutton.isOver(pos):
                Cbutton.clicked = True
            if Kbutton.isOver(pos):
                Kbutton.clicked = True
            if Nbutton.isOver(pos):
                Nbutton.clicked = True
            if Obutton.isOver(pos):
                Obutton.clicked = True
            if Wbutton.isOver(pos):
                Wbutton.clicked = True
            if Lbutton.isOver(pos):
                Lbutton.clicked = True
            if Ebutton.isOver(pos):
                Ebutton.clicked = True
            if Dbutton.isOver(pos):
                Dbutton.clicked = True
            if Gbutton.isOver(pos):
                Gbutton.clicked = True
            if Mbutton.isOver(pos):
                Mbutton.clicked = True
            if Tbutton.isOver(pos):
                Tbutton.clicked = True
           

    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a list for the objects. Add an object to the list when you click a button and draw all of the objects in the list:

```py
all_objects = []

def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(A,(0,0))
    
    if Abutton.clicked:
        all_objects.append( (A1, (0,0)) )
    if Cbutton.clicked:
        all_objects.append( (A2, (0,0)) )
    # [...] all the other buttons and objects

    for img, pos in all_objects:
        window.blit(img, pos)
```

Comment: I get this error ```for img, pos in all_objects:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable pygame.Surface object
``` when I add my images in the list ```all_objects = [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8]
```

Comment: Can you give me the full code because it is still not working for me.

Comment: I'm going to give you some great advice, stop asking someone to write the code for you. I'm sorry to have to say that, but you asked 37 Stack Overflow questions and learned nothing. You beg someone to write the code for you but do not even try it yourself. You will never learn to code by just copying the code. Let me finish with a quote: *"We learn more by looking for the answer to a question and not finding it than we do from learning the answer itself."* 
Lloyd Alexander, The Book of Three